# How to do authentication in Vuejs using azure AD?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, azure-active-directory, clientid

I need to authenticate my Vuejs Application through client secret in azure AD, I cannot find any article

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You haven't told us anything we can build upon to give you an answer. We don't know where you researched this, and it looks like you want us to tell you what to do or to find resources for you, either of which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server-side languages(back-end) such as c#, python..etc to work with client secret.

Both client id and client secret are used to identifying your application. The client id is public information and is ok to show to users. While secret must be kept secret or anyone could potently use your application credentials.

Vuejs is a javascript framework that runs on the client-side(browser). Client secret must always need to be secure and need to pass from the server-side such that no one from the browser can view the value of the client secret.

You must not use front end language such as Vuejs to manage client secret in Azure AD.

Also, Client secret is always not required. i.e., you can authenticate with Vuejs without Client secret, for example using [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).